# Mysql Geospatial point DB

Tags: mysql, geospatial, latitude-longitude, point

Im looking for a geospatial db which can search lat and long in seconds and point me to a point id. I'm new working with geopspatial db's. Can anyone recommend? or point me in a direction?

Comment: Are you looking at custom data or do you require full spatial functions available?  A simple table of distinct lon/lat points is a very real solution with immediate indexing.

Answer (score 2):

For spatial search you can try [Lucene/Solr spatial search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch). Store data in mysql and build the index in solr.

MyIASM table support spatial indexes in MySql, have a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use MySQL. All the freeness and familiarity, now with spatial functions. This is from wikipedia:

> MySQL DBMS implements the datatype geometry plus some spatial
>   functions that haven't been implemented according to the OpenGIS
>   specifications. Functions that test spatial relationships are limited
>   to working with minimum bounding rectangles rather than the actual
>   geometries. MySQL versions earlier than 5.0.16 only supported spatial
>   data in MyISAM tables. As of MySQL 5.0.16, InnoDB, NDB, BDB, and
>   ARCHIVE also support spatial features.